# Problem with Import 'package:adobe_xd/pinned.dart';

Tags: flutter, dart, adobe-xd

We cannot import the Pinned.dart package. Are available for any suggestion.

[Screenshot of my pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnH5M.png)

[Screenshot of my code showing the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewk7b.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pubspec.yaml` file is not formatted correctly and so the `adobe_xd` package is not downloaded nor added to your project, ensure the `adobe_xd` package starts from the same position as the package above it, it should look like the following:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  adobe_xd: ^2.0.0+1^
```

Additionally, the package has been added to `dev_dependencies` but is being used in run-time. Depending on what you're doing this may cause problems while building and running the app, a suggestion would be to move the `adobe_xd` package to the `dependencies` section of the `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  adobe_xd: ^2.0.0+1^
```